# UIcollectionView Cell set ZIndex . I want to create Card Cell using UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, cell

Swift 
I am trying to create card style cell. So i am using collection view and set `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt` in negative this code is working it looks good.

Problem is when I have a scroller bottom to top then first cell is a top side but I don't have a need on top here i have attached my code please check. I have Attached **Error Image** after scrolling issue

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let kItemSpace: CGFloat = -60.0

     @IBOutlet weak var collection_setting: UICollectionView!
     @IBOutlet var btn_top: UIButton!

     var ary: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

      var ary_show: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
          ary = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"]

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: - collection DataSource & Delegate
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.ary.count



    }

    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "smallCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! smallCollectionViewCell

            cell.inner_view.dropShadow()
            cell.inner_view.backgroundColor = .random()
           cell.layer.zPosition = -1
            cell.lbl_.text = "DEMO - \(indexPath.row)"
        //cell.bringSubview(toFront: collectionView)
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 100 )



    }
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {



    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: NSInteger) -> CGFloat {
        return kItemSpace
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)

        if(indexPath.row == 14)
        {
            print("--------------->",indexPath.row)
            cell.layer.zPosition = 0
        }else
        {
            cell.layer.zPosition = -1
        }

    }







}
```

[image]

Demo - 7 ,Demo - 8 , Demo - 9 is looking good but others are not showing as I want . first time this is looking correctly. this problem has come after scrolling.

Comment: Please check this url. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cards-collectionview-layout

Comment: Or this one https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hfcardcollectionviewlayout

Comment: This is available in objective c as well https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stickyflowlayout

Comment: cards-collectionview-layout is good. but i have done 90 percent I have to need only one zindex problem solution. And I am cant able to found solution.

Comment: Please give me solution Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code please.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "smallCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! smallCollectionViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell.inner_view.dropShadow()
        cell.inner_view.backgroundColor = .random()
     }
       cell.layer.zPosition = -1
        cell.lbl_.text = "DEMO - \(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cell.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(array.count - indexPath.row)